# Trading view vs Binance DMI calculation?

Tags: php, algorithmic-trading, binance, tradingview-api

I'm trying to calculate the directional movement indicator for 5m interval using the API of Binance. I'm using 288 values of "High", "Open" and "Close" and
I'm calculating the True range and then the Average True Range (ATR) with a simple moving average of a window with 14 values. I'm using the same Simple Moving average technique
for the calculation of the +DI, -DI and the ADX, but the values that I get don't match the ones that are shown in trading view for the DMI. I have also tried using an
exponential moving average the ATR, the +Di and the -DI, but I still don't get matching values. I have also noticed that the DMI of Binance and Trading view do not match.
Do you know which smoothing techinique is used by the DMI of trading view?

```
$url = 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=BNBBTC&interval=5m&limit=288';
$candles = file_get_contents($url);
$candles = json_decode($candles, true);

$arr_results = array();
$high = array();
$low  = array();
$close_arr = array();
$average = array();

for($i= 0; $i < sizeof($candles); $i++){
    array_push($high, $candles[$i][2]);
    array_push($low, $candles[$i][3]);
    array_push($close_arr, $candles[$i][4]);
    $av = ($candles[$i][2] + $candles[$i][3]) /2;
    array_push($average, $av);
}

$plus_di  = array_pop(trader_plus_di($high, $low, $close_arr, 14));
$minus_di = array_pop(trader_minus_di($high, $low, $close_arr, 14));
$adx      = array_pop(trader_adx ($high, $low, $close_arr, 14));
```

Comment: So from what I've read - your question comes down to *Do you know which smoothing techinique is used by the DMI of trading view?*  As SO is more about coding issues, working out what algorithms other sites use is probably out of scope.

Comment: Indeed, as the question is phrased it seems that I'm asking about the algorithm. However, having tried both options (SMA and EMA) and still not matching results, I assume that I have an error to the code itself or to the input values that I'm using.

Comment: As the input and output may need some subject knowledge it may be easier if you can give a specific example with the values you would expect and the values you get.  This way it would be easier to be able to try the code and validate the results.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the ATR, you need to smooth the TR (True Range) according to the following method :

Take a smoothing period nbCandles (nbCandles=14 candles typically), then:

- First ATR value: ATR(1) = Sum{TR(1 -> nbCandles)} (i.e you sum the nbCandles first values of the TR to get your first value of the ATR) - If nbCandles = 14 then your first ATR value will be the sum of the first 14 values of TR.
- Then, for the following ATR values, you use the following formula:

ATR(i) = ATR(i-1) - ATR(i-1)/nbCandles + TR(i)

Here is an example (based on 30 1 minutes candles historical record and 14 as the smoothing factor (number of candles used for smoothing)) :

[Binance BTCUSDT 1m](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8wyA.png)